# Hidden jQuery header

Tags: jquery, html, css, header

I'm hitting a brick wall with an idea I have for a header because I don't know what the 'effect' is called; even though I have seen it loads of times.

My idea is to have a hidden header, which will drop down when the user places their cursor at the top of the screen. Similar to the Windows 8 menu, which appears when you put your cursor in the corner of the screen.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

Comment: which corner? the charms menu or the task switcher?

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com Typically you hide the div off of the top of the screen and slide it into place during a hover event.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard I appreciate the link you Provided, yet I merely asked to be pointed in the right direction, not for a full working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/V9Cfn/2/

```
$(window).on('mousemove', function (e) {
   if (e.pageY < 100) {
       $("#showtop").slideDown();
   }
   else {
       $("#showtop").slideUp();        
   }
});
```

Essentially if the mouse is close enough to the top, show the div in question that you have fixed to the top.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems both ways would work! Ill try both and see which one works best for me!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `animate()`, instead of sliding the div down (using `slideDown` or `slideToggle`), this actually moves the entire div

http://jsfiddle.net/F6FRC/3/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        Shazam!
    </div>

    <div class="trigger">
    </div>
</div>​

$(function(){
    $(".trigger").mouseenter(function(){
        $('.header').animate({
            top: '0px',
            }, 500, function() {
        });
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $('.header').animate({
            top: '-20px',
        }, 500, function() {
        });
    });
});​



.wrapper   {position:relative;}
.header    {background-color: #F00; position:absolute; height: 20px; width: 100%; top: -20px; left: 0px;}
.trigger   {height: 50px; width: 100%; border: 1px solid #EFEFEF;}
​
```

Comment: Thanks for that, makes sense now! Ill have tinker and make it fit my needs.